# Firebase Select with multiple conditionals

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is it posible make this query in Firebase?
I need put OR conditionals where '//OR' is written blow.
Does anyone know how to do it?

```
firebase.database().ref().child('reservation')
.orderBy('date').equalTo(date)
//AND
  (  
     .orderBy('enterHourSelected').endAt(enterHourSelected)
     .orderBy('outHourSelected').startAt(enterHourSelected)
   //OR
     .orderBy('enterHourSelected').startAt(enterHourSelected)
     .orderBy('outHourSelected').endAt(outHourSelected)
   //OR
     .orderBy('enterHourSelected').endtAt(outHourSelected)
     .orderBy('outHourSelected').startAt(outHourSelected)
  )
  .once('value', snapshot => {
             ...
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible, you can only query on one child,key or value

So you are able to do this:

```
const ref=rootRef.child('reservation').orderBy('date').equalTo(date);
```

---

```
const ref=rootRef.child('reservation').orderBy('date').startAt("enterHourSelected").endAt(enterHourSelected);
```

---

```
const ref=rootRef.child('reservation').orderBy('date').limitToFirst(10);
```

---

```
const ref=rootRef.child('reservation').orderBy('date').limitToLast(10);
```

You will get an error if you execute the above code in the question

then when you want to retrieve data you can only use one of the above:

```
rootRef.child('reservation').orderBy('date').equalTo(date).once('value', snapshot => {
 //retrieve here

 });
```

Comment: Oficial firebase video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sKFLI5FOOHs&t=401s  Min: 10:30. The last query have 2 values (age and location).

Comment: yes as I said you can do that..each one alone..

Comment: Uhhh... bad news =(. Thanks!